# Convert pounds to pound decimals in Swift (2.2)

Tags: swift

How can I convert pounds to pound decimals?

For instance if the user enters **1.8 lbs**, I would like to be able to convert it to **1.5 lbs** so I can do some calculations.

The code below has two issues.

1- It only works when the user enters less then 10 (e.g 1.9) ounces since I'm multiplying the ounces by 10.

2- It only returns the decimal ounces, It does not return the whole number (pounds).

```
func poundsToDecimals(pounds:Double)->Double{
    let ounces = Double(pounds % 1)
    let decimals = ounces / 16 * 10
    return decimals
}

print(poundsToDecimals(1.4)) //prints... 0.25
```

Comment: I don't think that it makes sense to treat the input "pounds.ounces" as a *double*, that should be a string (otherwise 1.10 lbs < 1.8 lbs as numerical values). And how would you convert 1.2345? – Or use `Unit/NSMeasurement ` from Swift 3.

Comment: @ Martin R - I'm a little confused as to how to use `Strings` for the conversion, would you mind elaborating a little bit more on this? Thanks

Comment: This really is a bad user experience. If I type 1.5lbs I mean the equivalent of 1 lb 8oz., not 1lb 5oz. No one in the USA (does anyone else use our stupid system?) means 1lb 5oz when they type 1.5lbs.

Comment: @ rmaddy - This is exactly the problem I'm trying to solve. The user will enter `pounds/ounce (1.8oz)` but I need to convert it to decimals to be able to make some calculations, I think...

Comment: @fs_tigre: What I meant is that a quantity like "1 pound  8 ounces" should not be stored as a (single) floating point number "1.8" in the first place. Apart from the fact that it makes no sense – you might also suffer from rounding errors because numbers like 1.1 cannot be stored exactly in a binary floating point number.

Comment: @fs_tigre You missed my point. Don't make a user enter lbs/ozs as 1.8 or 1.5 or any decimal. If you were doing feet and inches no one would enter 5.10 to mean 5' 10". Don't use a decimal value to separate two completely different units (lbs and ounces). Either use two separate text fields, use a picker view with two columns, or if you want a single text field, let the user type "1lb 5oz" or whatever. If a user types "1.5" then they really mean one and half lbs, not one lb, five ounces.

Comment: @ rmaddy - Ah, I see, that makes a LOT of sense, in fact I will use two textFields instead. Thanks a lot for the good suggestion.

Comment: @MartinR - I see your point, It makes sense. Thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your first problem try converting it the number into a String and then split it up like so:

```
func poundsToDecimals(pounds: Double) -> Double {
    let numberAsString = String(pounds)
    var numbers = numberAsString.components(separatedBy: ["."])

    let seperatedPounds = Double(numbers[0])!
    let ounces = Double(numbers[1])!
    let decimals = ounces / 16 * 10

    return decimals
}
```

Can you please specify your second problem further. if you want to return more then one value you usally do it like this.

```
func poundsToDecimals(pounds: Double) -> (Double, Double) {
    let numberAsString = String(pounds)
    var numbers = numberAsString.components(separatedBy: ["."])

    let seperatedPounds = Double(numbers[0])!
    let ounces = Double(numbers[1])!
    let decimals = ounces / 16 * 10

    return (decimals, seperatedPounds)
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: @ benhofmann - What is `16.2`? I tested your code in Swift 2.2 and 3.0 and I get this error: `value of type 'String' has no member 'components'`

Comment: a sry i added it to test something i corrected the code in the aswer above

Comment: I cannot find the `components` method anywhere in the documentation. I'm getting Error: `value of type 'String' has no member 'components'`

Comment: which version of swift are you working with? This is for swift 3

Comment: try this if you use an older version: `numberAsString.componentsSeparatedByString(".")`

Comment: I tested it in Swift 2.2 and Swift 3.0 - I'm getting the same error with `componentsSeparatedByString`. http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5800e8ad34594805e10672e8

Comment: Have you tried it in XCode i don't have any proplems running that exact code. However there is another possibility which also workers in the IBM Sandbox one. Try this `var numbers = numberAsString.characters.split(separator: ".").map(String.init)`